# dealing with dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, date

I have columns in DataFrame which consist mainly of dates.
But there may also be strings or empty values.
I want to extract the year from the column but get an error because of string values.
Is there a way to apply universal solutions to that? Not only to get a year or month but also to apply other functions which could end with this error.
I mean, I would like to understand the nature of this problem and how to deal with it.

code is like

```
dates={'date':['11/03/2019','12/05/2021','','11/03/2021','x'],
      'date2':['11/04/2019','12/03/2021','11/06/2021',np.nan,'ab'],
}
df2=pd.DataFrame(dates)
df2['year'] =pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['date']).year
the error messages
```

Unknown string format: x

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
dates={'date':['11/03/2019','12/05/2021','','11/03/2021','x'],
      'date2':['11/04/2019','12/03/2021','11/06/2021',np.nan,'ab'],
}
df =pd.DataFrame(dates)
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors = "coerce")
df["date2"] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'], errors = "coerce")

df["year1"] = df["date"].dt.year
df["year2"] = df["date2"].dt.year
```

Output -

|  | date | date2 | year1 | year2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-11-03 00:00:00 | 2019-11-04 00:00:00 | 2019.0 | 2019.0 |
| 1 | 2021-12-05 00:00:00 | 2021-12-03 00:00:00 | 2021.0 | 2021.0 |
| 2 | NaT | 2021-11-06 00:00:00 | nan | 2021.0 |
| 3 | 2021-11-03 00:00:00 | NaT | 2021.0 | nan |
| 4 | NaT | NaT | nan | nan |

If you don't want any null values in your dataframe, do `df.dropna(inplace = True)` before adding the `year1` and `year2` columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following solution:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dates)
df2['year'] = [e[6:] if le(e) == 10 else None for e in df2['date']]
df2
```

**Output**:

[image: enter image description]

**Note**: the notation 'le' in the code corresponds to 'len'.